# Working with Jaspersoft iReport 4.1.3 need percentage of total of top ten revenue sums

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

I am currently working on Jaspersoft iReport 4.1.3.  The report I am generating requires a percentage of the top ten service Revenue customers.  I can easily get the top ten by limiting the the mysql to the top ten sums of service revenue by customer in a Dataset.  But how do I connect the variable to the total service revenue to get the percentage?

Thank you for any help you can give me.  Sherry

Comment: What is a formula of a percentage variable? (sumInGroup/sumInTheWholeReport)*100 - am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't completely precise. But I think this is what you need:

Create a text field with this expression: `$F{sales} / $V{Total}`
Its evaluation time should be `Auto`
Its Pattern should be `#,##0 %`

The variable $V{Total} is a `Sum` of $F{sales} with a reset type `Report`.